# Is there any way to let mapbox-navigation recognize custom tileset?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to make a **"AR campus application"** which can show very accurate details(directions, times) about destination in campus(college) and show it as AR with unity.

So I made a Dataset which contains informations about my college.(building name, building location, walkable path etc.)
[My Data set : details about college](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6w6j.jpg)
And with Navigation SDK, I could make a application which supports navigate-function.

But the problem is that the result gained by navigation is inaccurate. (maybe because of lack of information about Korea Map)
It works but doesn't show very accurate directions.
[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvgVJ.png)

What i'm thinking right now is **"let navigation recognize my tileset's road"** so that app can show more accurate direction.

**What I have tried**

- I added own tileset by adding layer in mapbox studio.
- tried to add own tileset directly in android studio, but couldn't find appropriate way

Is there any way to do this?

(I can't upload image becuase this is my first question here.
Please check embedded image file for more details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
I could make my own navigation by adding data to OSM.(OpenStreetMap)